# How can i have no answer questions(free text) using sharepoint 2010 survey

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I would like to have a free text with no answers.Can this be done using the
Sharepoint 2010 survey?
I would also like to have terms and condition at the end of the survey.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance